# How to revert the last migration?

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

I've made a migration that added a new table and want to revert it and delete the migration, without creating a new migration.

How do I do it? Is there a command to revert last migration and then I can simply delete the migration file?

Answer (score 1346):

You can revert by [migrating to the previous migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/migrations/#reversing-migrations).

For example, if your last two migrations are:

- `0010_previous_migration`
- `0011_migration_to_revert`

Then you would do:

```
./manage.py migrate my_app 0010_previous_migration
```

You don't actually need to use the full migration name, the number is enough, i.e.

```
./manage.py migrate my_app 0010
```

You can then delete migration `0011_migration_to_revert`.

If you're using Django 1.8+, you can show the names of all the migrations with

```
./manage.py showmigrations my_app
```

To reverse all migrations for an app, you can run:

```
./manage.py migrate my_app zero
```

Comment: for some reason this didn't work. but since I had a migrations mess I'm not sure this answer is not valid. anyway ended up solving this manually with sql editor, deleted the migration file, and re-created migrations. thanks anyway :)

Comment: I've seen many answers on SO to this problem that are old and simply don't work anymore. +1 because this works with Django 1.8.

Comment: Don't users typically also want to delete the migration file? I often find myself making a migration then rethinking it and recreating it before committing something clean, so I usually need to remember 'rm path/to/0011_migration_to_revert.py'

Comment: @Ness this only "de-migrates". If you don't wanna do that migration anymore you also need to delete the migration file.

Comment: As long as you are using your actual migration name, and not `'0010_previous_migration'`, I do not know why you would see that behaviour.

Comment: Here's an article explaining this too: https://www.techiediaries.com/how-to-reset-migrations-in-django-17-18-19-and-110/

Comment: When removing migration files from app/migrations/ be sure to delete both the 00nn_xxxx.pyc as well as the .py file.

Comment: This did revert the last migration however it did not remove it from django_migrations table.

Comment: Using django 2.1, this works for me: `/manage.py migrate my_app 0010`,  only `0010`, not the full file name.  After that, manually delete the local files appname/migrations/0011+, then manually delete row(s) from django_migrations db table for 0011+.

Comment: Maybe there was a space in your migration name? Then you'd have to enclose it with quotation marks.

Comment: This answer helped me so many times I wish I could upvote multiple times

Comment: THat's so dumb that it's `zero` and not `0000`.

Comment: @DevangHingu please ask a new question I can’t help in the comments

Answer (score 64):

Don't delete the migration file until after the reversion. I made this mistake and without the migration file, the database didn't know what things to remove.

```
python manage.py showmigrations
python manage.py migrate {app name from show migrations} {00##_migration file.py}
```

[If you want to revert all migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/migrations/#reversing-migrations), use `zero` as the name of the migration:

```
python manage.py migrate app_name_here zero
```

Delete the migration file.  Once the desired migration is in your models...

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Answer (score 50):

The answer by Alasdair covers the basics

- Identify the migrations you want by `./manage.py showmigrations`
- `migrate` using the app name and the migration name

But it should be pointed out that not all migrations *can* be reversed. This happens if Django doesn't have a rule to do the reversal. For most changes that you automatically made migrations by `./manage.py makemigrations`, the reversal will be possible. However, custom scripts will need to have both a forward and reverse written, as described in the example here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/migration-operations/

### How to do a no-op reversal

If you had a `RunPython` operation, then maybe you just want to back out the migration without writing a logically rigorous reversal script. The following quick hack to the example from the docs (above link) allows this, leaving the database in the same state that it was after the migration was applied, even after reversing it.

```python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations, models

def forwards_func(apps, schema_editor):
    # We get the model from the versioned app registry;
    # if we directly import it, it'll be the wrong version
    Country = apps.get_model("myapp", "Country")
    db_alias = schema_editor.connection.alias
    Country.objects.using(db_alias).bulk_create([
        Country(name="USA", code="us"),
        Country(name="France", code="fr"),
    ])

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = []

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(forwards_func, lambda apps, schema_editor: None),
    ]
```

This works for Django 1.8, 1.9

---

Update: A better way of writing this would be to replace `lambda apps, schema_editor: None` with `migrations.RunPython.noop` in the snippet above. These are both functionally the same thing. (credit to the comments)

Comment: From Django 1.8 onwards, you should use `RunPython.noop` instead of an inline lambda or equivelent: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/migration-operations/#django.db.migrations.operations.RunPython.noop

Comment: @SpoonMeiser In the syntax of the example, I think that looks like `migrations.RunPython(forwards_func, migrations.RunPython.noop)`. Need to check that functionally. That should get added as an answer or an edit to this one sometime.

Answer (score 16):

Here is my solution, since the above solution do not really cover the use-case, when you use `RunPython`.

You can access the table via the ORM with

```
from django.db.migrations.recorder import MigrationRecorder

>>> MigrationRecorder.Migration.objects.all()
>>> MigrationRecorder.Migration.objects.latest('id')
Out[5]: <Migration: Migration 0050_auto_20170603_1814 for model>
>>> MigrationRecorder.Migration.objects.latest('id').delete()
Out[4]: (1, {u'migrations.Migration': 1})
```

So you can query the tables and delete those entries that are relevant for you. This way you can modify in detail. With `RynPython` migrations you also need to take care of the data that was added/changed/removed. The above example only displays, how you access the table via Djang ORM.

Comment: When creating new models with ForeignKeys, with multiple migrations, then realising all is wrong, and restarting 2-3 migrations backward, with new models but sometimes same model names or same relationship names... this solution is clearly the winner. I had error message like `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "<relation name>" already exists` thus I made a `migrate --fake` which is wrong, so I tried to go back, then I got `psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "<other <relation name>" does not exist` THANKS

Answer (score 15):

To revert a migration:

```
python manage.py migrate <APP_NAME> <MIGRATION_NUMBER_PREFIX>
```

`MIGRATION_NUMBER_PREFIX` is the number prefix of the migration you want to revert to, for instance `0001` to go to `0001_initial.py` migration. then you can delete that migration.

> You can use `zero` as your migration number to revert all migrations of an app.

Answer (score 12):

I did this in 1.9.1 (to delete the last or latest migration created):

1. `rm <appname>/migrations/<migration #>*`

   *example:* `rm myapp/migrations/0011*`
2. logged into database and ran this SQL (postgres in this example)

   `delete from django_migrations where name like '0011%';`

I was then able to create new migrations that started with the migration number that I had just deleted (in this case, 11).

Comment: +1 Though this will work, You need to save this way as a last resort. Also you have to remember to edit/drop column/tables of which the problematic migration contributed.

Comment: good point - I used this when I created a migration but did not run "./manage.py migrate " yet

Comment: Absolutely dangerous and should not be at all. You can do it on your local machine, but that's a hack not a solution.

Answer (score 12):

First: find the previous migrations of your app,

`python manage.py showmigrations`

**eg:**

```
bz
 [X] 0001_initial
 [ ] 0002_bazifff
```

If you want rollback **0002_bazifff** migrations,

```
python manage.py migrate bz 0001_initial
```

If you want rollback **0001_initial** Or **all**

```
python manage.py migrate bz zero
```

It seems can't rollback **0001** only

Answer (score 10):

The other thing that you can do is delete the table created manually.

Along with that, you will have to delete that particular migration file. Also, you will have to **delete that particular entry in the django-migrations table**(probably the last one in your case) which correlates to that particular migration.

Comment: be carefull in this case - you are obligated to verify db to be adequate.

Comment: I would add VERY careful.  You could break a lot of things in Postgres, for example constraints.

Comment: this work if the table does not have foreign keys,
it's not recommended way

Answer (score 8):

You can revert by migrating to the previous migration.

For example use below command:

```
./manage.py migrate example_app one_left_to_the_last_migration
```

then delete `last_migration` file.

Answer (score 7):

If you are facing trouble while reverting back the migration, and somehow have messed it, you can perform `fake` migrations.

```
./manage.py migrate <name> --ignore-ghost-migrations --merge --fake
```

For **django version < 1.7** this will create entry in `south_migrationhistory` table, you need to delete that entry.

Now you'll be able to revert back the migration easily.

PS: I was stuck for a lot of time and performing fake migration and then reverting back helped me out.

Comment: This answer is for Django < 1.7.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is for similar cases **if the top answer by Alasdair does not help**. (E.g. if the unwanted migration is created soon again with every new migration or if it is in a bigger migration that can not be reverted or the table has been removed manually.)

> ...delete the migration, without creating a new migration?

**TL;DR**: You can delete a few last reverted (confused) migrations and make a new one **after fixing models**. You can also **use other methods** to configure it **to not create a table** by migrate command. **The last migration must be created so that it match the current models**.

---

**Cases** why anyone do not want to create a table for a Model that must exist:

**A)** No such table should exist in no database on no machine and no conditions

- *When:* It is a base model created only for model inheritance of other model.
- *Solution:* Set `class Meta: abstract = True`

**B)** The table is created rarely, by something else or manually in a special way.

- *Solution:* Use `class Meta: managed = False`
  The migration is created, but never used, only in tests. Migration file is important, otherwise database tests can't run, starting from reproducible initial state.

**C)** The table is used only on some machine (e.g. in development).

- *Solution:* Move the model to a new application that is added to INSTALLED_APPS only under special conditions or use a conditional `class Meta: managed = some_switch`.

**D)** The project uses multiple databases in `settings.DATABASES`

- *Solution:* Write a [Database router](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/multi-db/#automatic-database-routing) with method `allow_migrate` in order to differentiate the databases where the table should be created and where not.

---

The migration is created in all cases A), B), C), D) with Django 1.9+ (and  only in cases B, C, D with Django 1.8), but applied to the database only in appropriate cases or maybe never if required so. Migrations have been necessary for running tests since Django 1.8. The complete relevant current state is recorded by migrations even for models with managed=False in Django 1.9+ to be possible to create a ForeignKey between managed/unmanaged models or to can make the model managed=True later. (This question has been written at the time of Django 1.8. Everything here should be valid for versions between 1.8 to the current 2.2.)

If the last migration is (are) not easily revertible then it is possible to cautiously (after database backup) do a [fake revert](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46772762/448474) `./manage.py migrate --fake my_app 0010_previous_migration`, delete the table manually.

If necessary, create a fixed migration from the fixed model and apply it without changing the database structure `./manage.py migrate --fake my_app 0011_fixed_migration`.

Answer (score 1):

there is a good library to use its called djagno-nomad, although not directly related to the question asked, thought of sharing this,

scenario:  most of the time when switching to project, we feel like it should revert our changes that we did on this current branch, that's what exactly this library does, checkout below

https://pypi.org/project/django-nomad/

Answer (score 1):

All the other answers work great for rolling back linear migrations. However, when the migration is non-linear i.e has multiple leaf nodes and we wish to rollback only one path, then we can do in following way:

```
    X
  /   \
 A      B      [A and B can represent any number of linear migrations.] 
  \   /
    Y (merge migration)
```

If we need to rollback A,B and Y. Then we can do the way other answer states.
i.e `python manage.py migrate app X`.

However, if need to only unapply one path i.e, rollback B and Y, perform following steps:

1. Unapply only Y. By doing `python manage.py migrate app B (or A; both works)`.
2. Remove the migration files A and Y for time being from the project location.
3. Now unapply B, by doing `python manage.py migrate app X`.

Bring the migration files A and Y to the original location. Now, you can safely delete the unapplied migrations B and Y, if you wish to.

**The gist is django can only rollback migrations if the files are present in the location. If you do not want to rollback a migration path (i.e A here), remove it from the project location while performing rollback.**

More on this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/71231925/8663277

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a Reverse migration command in Django,
To remove th migrations changes from database directly,

for example if you have 4 migrations files in django app named (student)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akblY.png)
[python manage.py showmigrations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZO1W.png)

- Total 04 migrations Applied on Student Application.

[file structure : migrations file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsluN.png)

- file structure showing the migrations file list.

[remove migrations command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SR8nv.png)

- want to remove last 2 migrations from database,
  fire the command ( python manage.py migrate student 0002 )

[Show final migration list in database][5]

- final showmigrations list in database,
- successfully removed the last two migrations changes from databse.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I manually revert Django migration:

Backup everything (DB, code) before you doing this. Be extra cautious if you are doing this on Production db/environment.

Steps are as below:

- Delete the corresponding row in django_migrations table.
- Revert/delete tables and/or any other changes made by the migration. Be careful with this step and make sure after this, your Django system state (db/files) is the same as before migration.
- Remove the migration file (in app/migrations/00xx_) if you need to.

Notes:

- Try to do this on a Test Django app to see that this is simple.
- Learn more about [Django migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/migrations/) (backward/forward/zero)

Comment: Generally Django is able to reverse migrations it created on its own. Even if you create custom migrations, you can provide the reverse code / sql to Django to perform the reverse migration. This manual process should generally be avoided.

Comment: Agree. But its still needed when you get error running revert migration the normal way. This may happen, for example, when you accidentally remove your migration source file.