# Migration file errors when trying to get rid of a third party Django app

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

I'm working on a Django Project that currently uses the third party app Oscar. We're in the process of migrating away from Oscar, to a custom-built shop, and for this we want to get rid of a bunch of old files, models and of course the actual third party dependencies. But I am having a hard time doing this because the migration files keep throwing up errors.

The situation is that we have first-party models that depend on Oscar's models. For example:

```py
from oscar.apps.catalogue.models import Product


class Executable(Model):
    exec_hash = CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
    product = ForeignKey(Product, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=CASCADE)
    version = CharField(max_length=32)
    os = CharField(max_length=32)
    update_url = CharField(max_length=128, blank=True)
```

This means we have a migration file that contains the code to create this table:

```py
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name="Executable",
        fields=[
            ("id", models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name="ID")),
            ("exec_hash", models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)),
            ("version", models.CharField(max_length=32)),
            ("os", models.CharField(max_length=32)),
            ("update_url", models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=128)),
            (
                "product",
                models.ForeignKey(
                    blank=True, null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to="catalogue.product"
                ),
            ),
        ],
    ),
```

The `product` field from this `Executable` needs to be removed, so I removed the field from the model and created a new migration.

Now I want to remove all the Oscar apps from my `INSTALLED_APPS` list, but this is causing a whole lot of headaches because when I want to create or run any migration, I get this error:

```
ValueError: The field sr_app.Executable.product was declared with a lazy reference to 'catalogue.product', but app 'catalogue' isn't installed.
```

I've tried to simply remove this field from the initial migration file, but then in the next migration (where this field is actually being removed from the model), I get a key error:

```
Running migrations:
  Applying sr_app.0003_remove_executable_product...Traceback (most recent call last):
  [...snip...]
  File "/Users/kevin/Workspace/my_project_name/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 162, in state_forwards
    old_field = model_state.fields.pop(self.name)
KeyError: 'product'
```

So it seems that I have to keep Oscar installed and part of `INSTALLED_APPS` forever, because the initial migration uses this info? But this first migration is applied already, so it's kind of annoying that the initial migration needs to be valid for the next one to run.

How can I get around this problem? How can I get rid of Oscar (or any third party app) when my own initial migrations depend on that third party app?

Comment: It almost seems easier to nuke all the migrations, create a brand new one for the new state, and manually make all the database changes (it's just dropping tables and columns, so doable). Then fake-apply the migration. But surely there must be a better way that's reproducible on our server 

Comment: i think you need "squash" migrations
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40028586/how-to-squash-recent-django-migrations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got a very similar situation in my project. I've tried squashing the migrations, but have run into issues with circular dependencies which I have yet to resolve...

Having said this, you might want to try squashing the migrations (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/migrations/#squashing-migrations), as that would solve your issue - you would be able to delete the old migrations once your production deployments are updated to the point of these squashed migrations, and then you would be able to delete the app from your `INSTALLED_APPS` once all references to it are removed from your project and it's migrations.

In short, you run `./manage.py squashmigrations` with the app and migration number you want to squash up to, and Django will try to optimise the migrations by removing fields that were added and then removed in later migrations, among other things.

Comment: Okay so I’d have to keep the dependencies installed until all servers have run the migrations, then I can squash the migrations and then I can delete the dependencies. Not ideal, I was hoping to completely get rid of Oscar within one pull request :/

Answer (score 0):

The older migrations are there for compatibility reasons, you need them if you have more than one version of the database state in different locations (i. e. development & production servers, developers personal computers etc.)

If you are sure that no one uses older versions which aren't migrated yet, you do not need older migrations. So, just make sure everyone working on this project migrated on latest version of codebase, every server running this code migrated as well, and re-create migrations from scratch (delete all the migrations and make new ones).

Another workaround is to fake this table in older migrations: edit the very first migration introducing relations with third-party table in that way so it creates same model in your database and make sure every next migration uses this fake model instead of third-party model. Then edit the latest migration which deletes that relation so that would delete the fake model as well. This might also work.

Comment: You say "re-create migrations from scratch (delete all the migrations and make new ones)" but that is kind of vague. I can of course delete Oscar from my installed apps, make the model changes, and recreate the migration file (just as I said in my comment above). But that leaves me having to make the actual database changes by hand on staging and production since there is no real migration from old situation to new situation.

Comment: "edit the very first migration introducing relations with third-party table in that way so it creates same model in your database" - how do you do that? When that third-party app is gone, how do I edit the migration file and have it still create the same model?

Comment: You should be careful with deleting and recreating migrations when you have deployed to production! Django stores a record of which migrations have been applied to the database, so if you delete them and recreate it will cause problems.

Comment: Yes, I'd have to tinker with the migration table's content and fake-apply the migration. It should work, but it's not ideal since it won't be part of the normal deploy process where the migrations are always run.

Comment: "how do you do that? When that third-party app is gone, how do I edit the migration file and have it still create the same model?" — edit migration files by hand to make it look like it introduces a new model in your code (first migration to make Django think model is used) and then delete this model (to make Django actually remove DB table). You should use same database table name.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to migrate away from a third-party app in my Django project and encountered similar challenges with migration files and dependencies. Here's how I successfully did it:

**Step 1: Create a New Migration for Field Removal**

You needed to remove a field (product) from my Executable model, which depended on Oscar's 'catalogue' app. To do this, you should create a new migration specifically for this change:

```
python manage.py makemigrations your_app_name
```

In this new migration, you should remove the product field from the Executable model.

**Step 2: Update Dependencies in Migration Files**

In the new migration file (e.g., 0003_remove_executable_product.py), you have to update the dependencies. There was a line that looked like this:

```
dependencies = [
    ('sr_app', '0002_previous_migration'),
    ('catalogue', '0001_previous_migration'),  # Remove this line
]
```

You should remove the line with the dependency on 'catalogue' because you have to remove the field that depended on it.

**Step 3: Remove 'catalogue' from INSTALLED_APPS**

Now safely remove 'catalogue' from the INSTALLED_APPS list in Django project's settings.

**Step 4: Apply the Migrations**

Finally, run the migration again to apply the changes:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

**Step 5: Clean Up Oscar-Specific Code**

With the 'catalogue' app and the product field dependency removed, you cab start cleaning up any other Oscar-specific code in my project.

By following these steps, you will be most likely be able to safely remove the 'catalogue' app (Oscar) from your project without encountering the "lazy reference" error. Remember to back up your data and use version control (e.g., Git) to track changes during this process. Also, be cautious when removing third-party dependencies, as it may impact other parts of your project.

Comment: The migration that removes the field from my model already only depends on my own app. The problem is that the initial migration of my own app depends on Oscar, and trying to edit the initial migration file causes errors.