# Django Migrate from Char Field to Integer Field?

Tags: python, django, migration

I changed one of my CharField in models.py::

```
models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True)
```

into IntegerField -->

```
models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

I have data for that field, mainly empty strings(`""`) or integer as strings(eg: `"10"`).

So I would like to convert these strings to integer while migrate. eg::
if blank string(`""`) convert to `0`, else convert to integer.

How can i achive that while i do `./manage.py migrate` command?

here is the migration file created using `./manage.py makemigrations`::

```
# Generated by Django 2.1.2 on 2018-10-25 04:57

from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('dashboard', '0002_auto_20181024_1544'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='aclpermissions',
            name='ordering',
            field=models.IntegerField(default=0),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='submenus',
            name='ordering',
            field=models.IntegerField(default=0),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='subsubmenus',
            name='ordering',
            field=models.IntegerField(default=0),
        ),
    ]
```

When i run `./manage.py migrate` i got error ::

```
psycopg2.DataError: invalid input syntax for integer: ""
```

because there are fields with empty strings `""`.

**So I want to convert empty strings (`""`) to `0`.**

Comment: You changed one of my CharFields to an IntegerField. Which one? Your migration file show that you changed 3 fields.

Comment: @RedCricket i change 3 charfields to integerfield. i solved the problem by updating all the `empty strings` in db to `0`. now the `./manage.py migrate` command worked fine.

Comment: do you mean you updated all the empty values to the string "0"?

Comment: @RedCricket yes. after update i run `./manage.py migrate` which worked.

Comment: I would first create 3 new fields and write a [data migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/#data-migrations), then run a second migration that renames those 3 fields back.

Comment: @Selcuk I think creating new fields are not required since `migrate` command will do that job.

Answer (score 2):

For others coming upon this, you can add a function to run before the other migration operations:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    def blank_to_zero(apps, schema_editor):
        AclPermissions = apps.get_model('dashboard', 'AclPermissions')
        SubMenus = apps.get_model('dashboard', 'SubMenus')
        SubSubMenus = apps.get_model('dashboard', 'SubSubMenus')

        for obj in AclPermissions.objects.filter(ordering=''):
            obj.ordering = 0
            obj.save()

        for obj in SubMenus.objects.filter(ordering=''):
            obj.ordering = 0
            obj.save()

        for obj in SubSubMenus.objects.filter(ordering=''):
            obj.ordering = 0
            obj.save()

    dependencies = [
        ('dashboard', '0002_auto_20181024_1544'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(blank_to_zero),

        migrations.AlterField(... 
        # the rest of your operations
    ]
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/#data-migrations for info on editing data migrations.

Comment: Reduce to a single query per model: `AclPermissions.objects.filter(ordering='').update(ordering=0)`. Will save a lot of time if there are many objects.

Answer (score 1):

Change AlterField in your migration to RemoveField and then AddField -> note that this will drop your existing data!

```
    migrations.RemoveField(
        model_name='aclpermissions',
        name='ordering',
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='aclpermissions',
        name='ordering',
        field=models.IntegerField(default=0),
    ),
```

Answer (score -1):

Char/OLD:

```
email_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None)
```

Change it to Int/New:

```
email_type = models.IntegerField(default=None)
```

- python manage.py makemigration

Way to Change:

1. By losing data(Easy way)

> [Revert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32123477/how-to-revert-the-last-migration) migration to previous version

2. Without losing Data (Harder way)

> Open Python shell or Write a script to  -- chanage each values of 'email_type' to numbers (like 0, 1, 2, 3...)

And then

- python manage.py migrate