# Create model for existing database table in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have an old table in the database. And I want to create a model in Django application.
After creating a model and I used migrate command then it created a new table with its own name.

Comment: You can use `inspectdb` to generate a "sketch" model from a database table (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/legacy-databases/#auto-generate-the-models) But you probably will need to do some extra "scaffolding" yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the table name by setting [`db_table`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#db-table) on the model's `Meta` class. Set `managed = False` to prevent Django from creating the table.

```
class ExistingModel(models.Model):
    ...

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'existing_table'
        managed = False
```

After making these changes, I would [revert the previous migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32123477/django-revert-last-migration), remove the migration file, then run `makemigrations` again.

Comment: What about if you only want to temporarily have the table unmanaged, for a single migration, and then you want it managed afterward?  I am thinking of the situation where you have a pre-existing implicit m2m through table and later want to add an explict model for it.  Can you mark it as managed=False, makemigrations, migrate, and then mark it as managed=True afterward?

Comment: Apparently Django does changing an implicit through table to an explicit one, turns out.

Answer (score 5):

Django provides a utility to auto-generate models from an existing database via inspectdb command.

You can create models by introspecting an existing database by executing following command

```
python manage.py inspectdb
```

The above command will output all the models Django can create from the existing database to stdout. You can save this as a file by using standard Unix output redirection

```
python manage.py inspectdb > models.py # or pass the app_name.models.py if you want to generate them inside models.py file of specific app
```

The output file will be saved to your current directory. Move that file to the correct app and you have a good starting point for further customization.

you can refer https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-inspectdb for more information.