# Django Rest Framework no module named rest_framework but is installed

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I do my first steps with the Django REST Framework.
But when I do:

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations && python3 manage.py migrate
```

I get this error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rest_framework.renderers'

I have checked the settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'api',
    'rest_framework',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

I checked pip3 if the package is installed:

```
Django==3.0.5
django-rest-framework==0.1.0
djangorestframework==3.11.0
```

This is the code snippet where I use it and where I get the error:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from .models import Repo, Category
from .serializers import repoSerializer, categorySerializer
```

I do not know where the error is.
Can somebody give me a hint? Is maybe there a problem with the migration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to include this in `settings.py`

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
    ]
}
```

For more info: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/

Comment: Thanks, but get still the same error. Can I reset the migrations, maybe there is something in the cache.

Comment: It is not related to migration atm. For reverting, take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32124113/7994074

Comment: I cloud find the problem, something is wrong with my python under macOS. I need to run it as root. Then everything works perfectly. Thanks.