# django - relation already exists (special problem)

Tags: python, django

I made changes, created a new branch, committed, then migrated (after makemigrations).

But in that commit, it contained changes that I pulled remotely and it looked like my own.

I did not want this because I work on a team, so I made a new branch with only my changes.

The problem is, our database kept the migrations, but the code didn't.

So when I try to migrate, I get "migration already exists."

What do I do here? Is this a case where `--fake` would be useful?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to revert the last migration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32123477/how-to-revert-the-last-migration)

Comment: Are you expecting me to try this without knowing it will help me and possibly mess up my database?

Comment: How you try that is actually your own choice. Some people use test setups and backups but you seem to prefer the run-it-in-production-and-desaster way.

Comment: sorry if I offended you. just noticed, my migrations aren't even on production