# How to rollback non linear migrations in django?

Tags: django, database

Suppose I have following migrations in Django.

```
    X
  /   \
 A      B      [A and B can represent any number of linear migrations.] 
  \   /
    Y (merge migration).
```

Doing `python manage.py migrate app X` will unapply all of A, B and Y.
How can I unapply only B and Y?. And keep A as it is, i.e applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    X(*)      [* represent migration has been applied.]
  /   \
 A(*)   B(*)  [A and B can represent any number of linear migrations.] 
  \   /
    Y(*)      (merge migration)
```

**Steps to unapply only one path i.e B and Y**

1. Unapply only Y. By doing `python manage.py migrate app B (or A; both works)`.

   ```
      X(*)     
    /    \
   A(*)   B(*) 
    \    /
      Y()
   ```
2. Remove the migration files A and Y for time being from the project location.

   ```
     X(*)     
      \
       B(*)
   ```
3. Now unapply B, by doing `python manage.py migrate app X`.

   ```
     X(*)     
      \
       B()
   ```
4. Bring the migration files A and Y to the original location. You can now safely delete the unapplied migrations B and Y, if you wish to.

   ```
     X(*)     
    /   \
   A(*)  B() 
    \   /
      Y()
   ```

**The gist is, django can only rollback migrations if the files are present in the location. If you do not want to rollback a migration path (i.e A here), remove it from the project location while performing rollback.**